# JQuery 1.7 breaks JQuery Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-1.7

One of the best datepickers around these days I think is still Kelvin Luck's jquery-datepicker

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

However, the latest jquery (jquery 1.7+) breaks this datepicker silently. I was just wondering if anyone has looked into the issue, or how we can fix this potentially

Comment: Have you [contacted](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/list) the author of the plugin?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery UI datepicker? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: FYI, going to the sample pages for that datepicker, half of them don't work in any modern browser anyways.  I think the code is just outdated and broken.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the datepicker from jquery-ui, I don't know if it is different but it seems more in sync with jquery releases, has a larger user base and developer pool.

Answer (score 0):

They did fix it for jQuery 1.7.

The code is maintained on GitHub here: https://github.com/vitch/jQuery-datepicker

An update to the fix for jQuery 1.7 is mentioned here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/377

I updated to the latest version in a client application today and am able to get the DatePicker to appear now in jQuery 1.7. At this moment, the latest commit to their GitHub repo is from August 2014, so it's been more than a year... as long as it's been stable since then I see no reason why it should have needed frequent updating.