# jQuery simple drop down datepicker

Tags: jquery

Can you suggest me very simple drop down datepicker that only show today date.On click to show past 3 or 4 months for example and nothing else.In format dd/m/Y .I tried jQuery datepicker but did't like it.Any other suggestion?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this one](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/). There are many demos if you scroll a bit down. I took into use to one project couple of years ago, and it works just fine.

Hopefully, it will get you going.

Comment: I am sure I read a question on SO the other day where new versions of jQuery didn't work with this plugin

Comment: @bateman_ap, thanks for the comment, that's good to know. Could you please try to find and post a link to that question? I'll make a search myself..

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525089/jquery-1-7-breaks-jquery-datepicker

Comment: Thanks again for the info. It says in the post that it breaks at 1.7+. @Lyubomir Vanyov, could you please write what jQuery version you are using?